# Hamming 7,4 encoder with generator matrix

Tags: matlab, hamming-code

(My problem concerns matlab, but I guess any general programming viewpoint is also okay)

I have a question regarding Hamming(7,4) encoder where generator matrix is used.

Let's assume that I have already created the generator matrix, code word and encoded that with the error control bits, giving me a variable `encoded_sequence` for example. This `encoded_sequence` is of length `1x7000` double, where 500 of random error control coding bits are encoded with the codeword `c`, with the help of the Generator matrix.  Let's assume that a random codeword is `[0,0,0,1,0,1,1]`.

Now, How do I "implement" the `encoded_sequence` with the actual data bits that I want to simulate?

(Keep in mind that at the end of the program a decoding is also implemented, doing the reverse, so please only tips which can be translated back to d the reverse at the decoder)

I have tried padding the transmitted bits with zeros but I do now know how to make it so it makes sense functionality wise.

I have also tried concentrating the matrixes `[encoded_sequence; databits]` but I know you the idea is not to add them together without "mixing up".

Comment: Perhaps you only need to concatenate the matrices / vectors. Please provide a minimal example with (small) inputs and desired output